# How can I monitor everything on a server with PHP to find where a fault is?

Tags: php, error-handling, incompatibility

I have taken over some patching work for a company, they didn't want to redo the system with a new system, so I am left with patching up what they have. So the server they rented upgraded the server from 5.3 to 5.5, and some problems startet to arise. The users who where logged in where logged out after a short while (if one pressed F5 they would be logging in again) and there is a chat which are updated with ajax and entered into sql. This has worked as "auto update", so one always sees the last and most updated message. Now the database is updated, but not all users get the latest message, they have to press F5.

This system has many scripts and a lot of old fashioned PHP coding (was intended for PHP4), I have a difficulty finding all the faults. I have fixed a lot, but not all. So I am asking for a script or something so that it can scan for incompabilitys, find hidden error messages and such things. Is there a thing like this in existence?

I also have no controll over installed applications on the server, it's just a rental.

Comment: Take a look at [PHP Compatibility for PHPCS](https://github.com/wimg/PHPCompatibility) to identify all potential version issues for the new version of your PHP

Comment: can I install this script without having access to the server except ftp?

Comment: You run it against the source code..... it doesn't have to be on the webserver, it can be on your development box

Answer (score 2):

Go through all of the PHP 5.3 to 5.4 changes and then 5.4 to 5.5 change notes regarding removed features and changed features. Then do a global search across your source code (you will probably have to download it all if you don't have a local copy, it's not feasible to do this via ftp... would take forever.) for those specific methods/functions that have changed or been removed.

Should not take more than an hour or two to audit all the changes.

[PHP 5.3 -> 5.4 Migration](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php)

[PHP 5.4 -> 5.5 Migration](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.incompatible.php)

Comment: I tried this, but it still is not working as it should. I serached the server using bash on ssh with putty, and found the files which contained function that were removed, but that made the site work, but not functionally complete. It was a blank white page before I fixed that.